# "Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT", trying to put mitmproxy behind nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, mitmproxy

I have a mitmproxy running on port 2011. I can use it by itself, with `curl -x http://127.0.0.1:2011 google.com`. However, I now want to put it behind nginx under the domain name `proxy.history.test`. However, doing `curl -x http://proxy.history.test:80 google.com -L -v` fails with

```
* Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT
* CONNECT phase completed!
* Closing connection 1
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT
```

My `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        /dev/null;

daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    map $http_host $service_port {
        hostnames;
        default '';


        proxy.history.* 2011;
        }

    proxy_temp_path ./tmp;
    access_log /dev/null;
    ssl_certificate ./cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ./key.pem;
    #proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    client_body_temp_path ./tmp;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    client_max_body_size 50m;


    server {
            listen       127.0.0.1:443 ssl;
    
            server_name  *.test;
    
            location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$service_port;

            }
        }



        server {
                    listen       127.0.0.1:80;
                    
                    server_name  *.test;
                    

                    return 302 https://$http_host$request_uri;

                }

    

        
}
```

(I have to specify `:80` in the curl command, because otherwise, it will try to connect to port `1080`, for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` is a reverse proxy and not a forward proxy and doesn't support `HTTP` `CONNECT` method. You'll need to find a third-party `nginx` module to support `CONNECT`.

Comment: Does `nginx` have to be recompiled for that module, or can it be loaded in dynamically (like DKMS)?

Comment: https://github.com/chobits/ngx_http_proxy_connect_module :) 

It's not the best dev experience, but it works.

Comment: Nginx can work as a transparent forwarding proxy with the TCP/UDP Stream module. But only for one specific destination, not dynamically forwarded. For that the proxy_connect module from the previous comment is needed.